# Changing default values for LDAP loginShell and homeDirectory

Tags: linux, ldap, nfs, openldap, shell

Is it possible to set default values in the LDAP server for every newly created LDAP user for loginShell and homeDirectory for Linux users? I know how to change it on a per user bases but this is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sssd` to manage users, then you can update the `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file to overwrite the defaults. For example to enforce `/bin/false` to all users except root:

```
[sssd]
domains = LDAP
services = nss
config_file_version = 2

[nss]
filter_users = ['root']
filter_groups = ['root']
override_homedir = /tmp
override_shell = /bin/false
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't override the shell. I tried setting all the following:

override_shell = /bin/false
default_shell = /bin/false
shell_fallback = /bin/false
vetoed_shells = /bin/sh

but I can still login. Any ideas?